# hiding elements with javascript vs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was wondering about hiding elements with DOM, the person in the course is doing this by setting the display to none

```
document.getElementById("id-name-1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("id-name-2").style.display="none";
```

We are hiding two elements here, now both elements have the same class. I have been converting what the course is showing me into jQuery as well for added challenge. The jQuery code that I used is as follows, the name of the class they both has is say dice.

```
$(".dice").hide();
```

This hides both elements at the same time, which way would be better? I know that if I had other elements with class dice it would also hide them. So maybe that is why the other way is better? Thank you for your thoughts -- I am new to this.

Stephen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Same. There is no immediate difference. jQuery is a Framework for JavaScript. So either is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is open ended. No right or wrong answer.

```
$(".dice").hide();
```

As mentioned, this will hide all elements with Class "dice". If you want to be more specific, you can be:

```
$("#id-name-1", "#id-name-2").hide();
```

This selector uses IDs and selects both elements.

Your selector can be more vague or more precise as needed.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't even think about a multi selection, good information there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use vanilla javascript, can do something like

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('className').forEach(el => el.style.display = "none")
```

I recommend you use vanilla javascript instead of JQuery because is most probably that you will use javascript than jquery in a new project. and on the other hand, will be more easy for you use libraries like react if you have a good vanilla javascript foundation.

Comment: OK thanks, I wasn't sure if I should be branching off into jQuery or not. Maybe I'll just stick with vanilla for now until I get it down better. Thanks again for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Document.querySelectorAll(".dice") would also be able to the above based on the style using purely javascript. So it all comes down to preference since it works the same way with display:none;.
Also,.hide() takes in optional arguments/callback functions which can help with hiding the element(s).

Comment: I see never really thought about doing it that way, I not sure why. Maybe I was just to focused on learning jQuery to thing of doing it with vanilla. Thanks you for your answer